# #include <xc.h> not accepted

Tags: c, microchip

I'm trying to program a PIC microcontroller, however, every time I attempt to include <xc.h>, I keep receiving the same error, "Unresolved inside include file".

Here's what I'm trying:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Header.h"

#define _XTAL_FREQ 4000000

int main(void)
{

}
```

Note that inside the #include "Header.h" are my #pragma and the #include <xc.h>, which keeps being recognized as an error. Does anyone know why #include <xc.h> keeps failing like this? I also tried including it directly in the source file, but nothing changed.

By request, I'm including the contents of the header file, "Header.h" (How creative), I wouldn't advise reading through all the #pragma, it's quite cramped:

```
// PIC24EP32MC202 Configuration Bit Settings

// 'C' source line config statements

// FICD
#pragma config ICS = PGD1               // ICD Communication Channel Select bits (Communicate on PGEC1 and PGED1)
#pragma config JTAGEN = OFF             // JTAG Enable bit (JTAG is disabled)

// FPOR
#pragma config ALTI2C1 = OFF            // Alternate I2C1 pins (I2C1 mapped to SDA1/SCL1 pins)
#pragma config ALTI2C2 = OFF            // Alternate I2C2 pins (I2C2 mapped to SDA2/SCL2 pins)
#pragma config WDTWIN = WIN25           // Watchdog Window Select bits (WDT Window is 25% of WDT period)

// FWDT
#pragma config WDTPOST = PS32768        // Watchdog Timer Postscaler bits (1:32,768)
#pragma config WDTPRE = PR128           // Watchdog Timer Prescaler bit (1:128)
#pragma config PLLKEN = ON              // PLL Lock Enable bit (Clock switch to PLL source will wait until the PLL lock signal is valid.)
#pragma config WINDIS = OFF             // Watchdog Timer Window Enable bit (Watchdog Timer in Non-Window mode)
#pragma config FWDTEN = ON              // Watchdog Timer Enable bit (Watchdog timer always enabled)

// FOSC
#pragma config POSCMD = NONE            // Primary Oscillator Mode Select bits (Primary Oscillator disabled)
#pragma config OSCIOFNC = OFF           // OSC2 Pin Function bit (OSC2 is clock output)
#pragma config IOL1WAY = ON             // Peripheral pin select configuration (Allow only one reconfiguration)
#pragma config FCKSM = CSDCMD           // Clock Switching Mode bits (Both Clock switching and Fail-safe Clock Monitor are disabled)

// FOSCSEL
#pragma config FNOSC = FRCDIVN          // Oscillator Source Selection (Internal Fast RC (FRC) Oscillator with postscaler)
#pragma config PWMLOCK = ON             // PWM Lock Enable bit (Certain PWM registers may only be written after key sequence)
#pragma config IESO = ON                // Two-speed Oscillator Start-up Enable bit (Start up device with FRC, then switch to user-selected oscillator source)

// FGS
#pragma config GWRP = OFF               // General Segment Write-Protect bit (General Segment may be written)
#pragma config GCP = OFF                // General Segment Code-Protect bit (General Segment Code protect is Disabled)

// #pragma config statements should precede project file includes.
// Use project enums instead of #define for ON and OFF.

#include <xc.h>
```

Comment: `#include <xc.h>` will only work if `xc.h` is in the include path. Have you tried `#include "xc.h"`? Or perhaps you didn't install the full library suite properly.

Comment: As @WeatherVane pointed preliminary thoughts are "header file not in the default search path".  But this point of yours "I also tried including it directly in the source file, but nothing changed." indicates the problem is something else. Why don't you share what is in the ``xc.h`` header file? Thanks.

Comment: @MohithReddy I thought that meant OP had put `#include <xc.h>` in the .c file instead of in the other header file – not copy/pasted the header content.

Comment: Please post the *complete and unmodified* text of *everything* the compiler printed when you tried to compile this file. I suspect the error message doesn't mean what you thought, but I need to see exactly what it said to be sure.

Comment: zwol, to clarify, when I stated an error came up with the #include <xc.h> command, I meant it didn't recognize it in the first place (As in a red, wavy line appears underneath the line of code), I have not yet compiled this code due to the error I'm facing at the moment.

Comment: @Damascus Please try compiling the code. Sometimes, red wavy lines are false alarms due to mismatches between the compiler and your development tools.

Comment: It seems that <xc.h> works, I'm able to build and run the project while <xc.h> still showed up with the wavy line. However, I'm unable to type in any of my TRIS and PORT registers, which I suspect is due to <xc.h> somehow.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way you should start:

```
#include <xc.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Header.h"

#define _XTAL_FREQ 4000000

int main(void)
{

}
```

and remove `#include <xc.h>` from your file `Header.h`

Comment: Do you know why it must be included first?